# How to add custom fields In manage products general tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-field

I want to create some **extra fields** in **catalog->manage product-> general** tab section.

give me some suggestion

Comment: you can add custom field using product attributes section.. check this out :
https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't know that Magento uses `EAV structure` to store product, customer, customer address, and category data

You can create product attribute from admin panel assign to it general tab from admin

You can follow Magento official doc for it

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/attribute-create.html